# I am trying to create a website from a psd template and I struggle with the header section

Tags: css, html

Good evening everyone,

As stated in the title I try to recreate a website from a psd template I found (as practise ofcourse).

The problem I have is when I try to recreate the header part of the website I struggle to keep them in one 'box' because afterwards I need to have both of the logo and ul list in a border with a black background and with opacity set to 0.3 (which I know how to do and is not a issue).

Any help would be awesome, I did try to use some of the new HTML5 syntax like  which did not work perhaps cause of the same issue as I have now.

I attach my code:

```
<div id="header">
  <p id="logo">Brandi <span id="line"> | </span> <span id="tag">I'am your tag line</span></p>
  <ul id="nav">
    <a href="#">
      <li>Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>Features</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>Works</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>Team</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>Contact</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
body {
width: 100%
margin: auto;}

#logo   {
float: left;
font-size: 28pt;
font-family: Pacifico;
color: black;
padding: 0 100px;}

#tag {
font-family: Open Sans;
font-style: Regular;
font-size: 12pt;
color: #666;}

#line {
color: deepskyblue;
font-family: Open Sans;
font-style: Regular;
font-size: 20pt;
padding: 0 20px;}

#nav {
float: right;
list-style: none;
padding: 30px 0;}

#nav a {
font-family: Open Sans;
font-style: Regular;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 20px 20px;
color: black;}

a:hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid deepskyblue;}
```

Comment: What do you mean by keeping them in one box? Like in a row?

Comment: I am really sorry if I did not explain ir properly, by box I mean the CSS kind of box, so that I can style both of them at the same time as I will need to have a background on that header throughout the whole width of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of well-formed HTML, I will recommend nesting your `<a`> tags inside your `<li>` instead of the other way round. (Refer docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)). Looking at your codes, your `<div id="header">` already forms a box around your `#logo` and `#nav`.

For refresher, check out [HTML Block Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) and [Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model).

See if these [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/wpo557sf/) do what you want.

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow: auto;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    font-size: 28pt;
    font-family: Pacifico;
    color: black;
    padding: 0 100px;
}

#tag {
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-style: Regular;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #666;
}

#line {
    color: deepskyblue;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-style: Regular;
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

#nav li{
    float: right;
}

#nav a {
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-style: Regular;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    color: black;
}

a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <p id="logo">Brandi<span id="line"> | </span><span id="tag">I'am your tag line</span></p>
    <ul id="nav">      
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: +1, but it's about much more than simply having _"well formed HTML"_... it's about following the W3C HTML markup standards so that code will perform predictably across browsers.  After all, you can also have HTML that is not well formed but still follows the W3C standards.

Comment: That's amazing, thank you very much for helping. I came out with the answer yesterday before I went to bed and couldn't do anything till now, overflow: hidden and auto were the CSS property I needed to make it work.